# HTTP error 401 when Retrieving an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Im trying to retrieve an image in the Layouts mapped folder. I have the following code to do that

```
var imageUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_layouts/CGCDocumentHistoryView/Images/eskom.png";
byte[] imageData;

using (var webclient = new WebClient())
{
   imageData = webclient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
}
```

When i execute this i get a 401 error. How can i fix this

Comment: 401 = Unauthorized. You need to be authorized to access the webpage, which in HTTP usually means sending credentials.

Answer (score 0):

401 error means "Unauthorized". You have to check your permissions to access that file.

AuthDiag (Authentication and Access Control Diagnostics)  is a tool that should help you with these problems in IIS servers.

You can find more information on this Microsoft Troubleshooting page.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273/en

```
try
{
  var imageUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_layouts/CGCDocumentHistoryView/Images/eskom.png";
  byte[] imageData;

  using (var webclient = new WebClient())
  {
     imageData = webclient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Check the exception
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing that in code without tampering with iis

Comment: You can try catching the Exception and reading the information it provides you.

Comment: Could I help you resolving the problem?